# issues to build APK react native app in Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, apk

[image]

> > Configure project :react-native-vector-icons 
> >     WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
> >     It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

```
error: resource 
android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource                     
android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
/home/aras/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/37bde114cf44a5a3196253573d3981be/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

/home/aras/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/37bde114cf44a5a3196253573d3981be/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

/home/aras/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/37bde114cf44a5a3196253573d3981be/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.

/home/aras/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/37bde114cf44a5a3196253573d3981be/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

/home/aras/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/37bde114cf44a5a3196253573d3981be/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

/home/aras/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/37bde114cf44a5a3196253573d3981be/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

error: failed linking references.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-user-agent:verifyReleaseResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
75 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 73 up-to-date
```

Comment: i have the same issue too

Comment: I have that issue and i solved this because my app did not link to my package. after link, I get some mismatch error off package, but I change the version of package issue was solved. @YaserDarzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for gradle dependency for **support library version** mismatch in your all npm build.gradle.